# Joining two Tables in Hive using HiveQL(Hadoop)

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query JOIN with Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386368/sql-query-join-with-table)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestingTable1   (This is the MAIN table through which comparisons need to be made)
(
BUYER_ID BIGINT,
ITEM_ID BIGINT,
CREATED_TIME STRING
)
```

And this is the data in the above first table

```
**BUYER_ID**  |  **ITEM_ID**     |      **CREATED_TIME**   
--------------+------------------+-------------------------
 1015826235      220003038067       *2001-11-03 19:40:21*
 1015826235      300003861266        2001-11-08 18:19:59
 1015826235      140002997245        2003-08-22 09:23:17
 1015826235     *210002448035*       2001-11-11 22:21:11
```

This is Second table in Hive- It also contains information about the items we are purchasing.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestingTable2
(
USER_ID BIGINT,
PURCHASED_ITEM ARRAY<STRUCT<PRODUCT_ID: BIGINT,TIMESTAMPS:STRING>>
)
```

And this is the data in the above second table (`TestingTable2`)-

```
**USER_ID**    **PURCHASED_ITEM**
1015826235     [{"product_id":220003038067,"timestamps":"1004941621"},    {"product_id":300003861266,"timestamps":"1005268799"},    {"product_id":140002997245,"timestamps":"1061569397"},{"product_id":200002448035,"timestamps":"1005542471"}]
```

**Compare `TestingTable2` with `TestingTable1` so that below scenario is fulfilled.**

Find the `PRODUCT_ID` AND `TIMESTAMPS` from `TestingTable2` WHICH IS NOT MATCHING WITH `ITEM_ID` AND `CREATED_TIME` from TestingTable1 CORRESPONDING TO `BUYER_ID(USER_ID)` after comparing from `TestingTable1`.

So If you look `TestingTable2` data this(last) `ITEM_ID 210002448035` from `TestingTable1` is not matching with `TestingTable2` `PRODUCT_ID- 200002448035`  data and similarly with timestamps. So I want to show the below result using the HiveQL query.

```
**BUYER_ID**  |  **ITEM_ID**     |      **CREATED_TIME**          |  **PRODUCT_ID**    |     **TIMESTAMPS** 
--------------+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------
1015826235          *210002448035*           2001-11-11 22:21:11            200002448035           1005542471 
1015826235       220003038067           *2001-11-03 19:40:21*           220003038067          1004941621
```

Can anyone help me with this. As I am new to HiveQL so having lot of Problem.

**Updated:-**

I have written this query, but it doesn't working the way I wanted to.

```
select * from 
  (select * from 
     (select user_id, prod_and_ts.product_id as product_id, prod_and_ts.timestamps as timestamps 
      from testingtable2 LATERAL VIEW
      explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts)
      prod_and_ts 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN testingtable1 
  ON ( prod_and_ts.user_id = testingtable1.buyer_id AND testingtable1.item_id =    prod_and_ts.product_id
     AND prod_and_ts.timestamps = UNIX_TIMESTAMP (testingtable1.created_time)
  )
  where testingtable1.buyer_id IS NULL) 
  set_a LEFT OUTER JOIN testingtable1 
  ON (set_a.user_id = testingtable1.buyer_id AND  
  ( set_a.product_id = testingtable1.item_id OR set_a.timestamps = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(testingtable1.created_time) )
 );
```

**One More UPDATE**

As per `user1166147` comments. I wrote my query as per his query. 
In hive I guess `INNER JOIN` are written by simply `JOIN`.

This is my below query.

```
select * from (select t2.buyer_id, t2.item_id, t2.created_time as created_time, subq.user_id, subq.product_id, subq.timestamps as timestamps 
from
(select user_id, prod_and_ts.product_id as product_id, prod_and_ts.timestamps as timestamps from testingtable2 lateral view explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts) subq JOIN testingtable1 t2 on t2.buyer_id = subq.user_id 
AND subq.timestamps = unix_timestamp(t2.created_time)
WHERE (subq.product_id <> t2.item_id)
union all
select t2.buyer_id, t2.item_id as item_id, t2.created_time, subq.user_id, subq.product_id as product_id, subq.timestamps
from 
(select user_id, prod_and_ts.product_id as product_id, prod_and_ts.timestamps as timestamps from testingtable2 lateral view explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts) subq JOIN testingtable1 t2 on t2.buyer_id = subq.user_id 
    and subq.product_id = t2.item_id 
    WHERE (subq.timestamps <> unix_timestamp(t2.created_time))) unionall;
```

And after running the above query, I am getting zero result back.

**One Final UPDATE:-**

My Bad, I didn't have the accurate data in the tables so that is the reason I was not getting the result back. Yes it is working the actual above query.

Comment: @biziclop, Thanks for editing, Any suggestion how can I achieve the result that I want to?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Hive expert, maybe someone else :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" referring to the query? What are the results you obtain?

Comment: First of all, I am getting error as `OR is not allowed in JOIN query` with HiveQL. And If i change that to some other like `AND` I don't get any result back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT - PART 1**
Okay - For some reason I am going to explain myself - so to start with I stumbled upon this question because of the SQL tag, and saw Hive, and started to not look and just skip it. BUT then I noticed it had been over a day and you had gotten no answers.  I looked - I saw a SQL logic correction in the original query posted that I knew would be needed and would help, so I posted ONLY because no one had answered. I will try to address this last question - but after that I am keeping my advice to myself, as I may be giving bad advice.  Good luck!  I tried!  And you seem to be getting answers now, so...

**In TSQL, I could solve this entire problem with the below single query**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SO_Table1HIVE A
FULL OUTER JOIN SO_Table2HIVE B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.[USER_ID] AND (B.t1time = A.Created_TIME OR B.PRODUCTID = A.ITEM_ID)
```

It would return everything, including your match buyer_id/user_id only.  It won't match a buyer_id/user_id row with no matches in either time or product in the other table, but it will return it as a separate row with NULLS in the other table's fields.  I would not match these any way - there is no accurate information provided to do it with as explained below.

**END EDIT PART 1**

If you can't do `FULL OUTER JOIN` with `OR` in Hive, the simplest way to meet the original criteria is to `UNION ALL` 2 `INNER JOIN`s.  On one of the queries, in addition to joining the matching user_ids, join on the PRODUCT_ID AND in your `WHERE` look for TIMESTAMPS that don't match CREATED_TIME.  On the second query, in addition to joining the matching user_ids, join on the times AND in your `WHERE` look for products that don't match.

**EDIT PART 2 - UPDATE FOR COMMENT QUESTION ADDITIONAL CRITERIA**

If I understand the last criteria it is any record in either table that has a matching user_id = buyer_id, but nothing else matches.  The `FULL OUTER JOIN` with `OR` condition will return them, but there isn't enough provided info for a way to relate the records to each other.  We can easily identify them, but have no way to tie them back to each other.  If you do so and you have more than one record without a match in either OR both tables, there are going to be multiple entries for each.

*Any query I wrote to try to tie them without more info (and probably with) would be a guess and inaccurate.*

For example, in the first table if there were these 2 (sample fake) records with nothing matching in the second except user_id:

```
1015826235  420003038067    2011-11-03 19:40:21.000
1015826235  720003038067    2004-11-03 19:40:21.000
```

AND in table2 - these non matching:

```
1015826235  {"product_id":520003038067,"timestamps":"10...
1015826235  {"product_id":620003038067,"timestamps":"10...
```

You can identify them, but if you match them without more criteria you get 4 instead of 2:

```
1015826235  420003038067    2011-11-03 19:40:21.000 1015826235 520003038067
1015826235  420003038067    2011-11-03 19:40:21.000 1015826235 620003038067
1015826235  720003038067    2004-11-03 19:40:21.000 1015826235 520003038067
1015826235  720003038067    2004-11-03 19:40:21.000 1015826235 620003038067
```

My suggestion would be simply to identify them and show them, as below.

```
BUYER_ID        ITEM_ID      CREATED_TIME           USER_ID PRODUCTID   timestamps  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL            NULL         NULL                   1015826235  520003038067    2009-11-11 22:21:11.000
NULL            NULL         NULL                   1015826235  620003038067    2008-11-11 22:21:11.000
1015826235      420003038067 2011-11-03 19:40:21.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    
1015826235      720003038067 2004-11-03 19:40:21.000    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**END EDIT PART 2 - UPDATE FOR COMMENT QUESTION ADDITIONAL CRITERIA - PART 1**

I am working with TSQL, so I can't test for you an exact query with your syntax, but the  concepts of the joins are the same, and this will return what you want.  I did take your query and attempt your syntax, modify as needed.  I tested in TSQL.  You may be able to take this and improve upon it with functionality in HiveQL.  There are other ways to do this - but this is the most straightforward and this will translate to HiveQL.

**REMOVED, YOU GOT THIS PART AND IT IS INCLUDED LATER**

(*Again modify syntax as needed*)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT BUYER_ID,ITEM_ID,CREATED_TIME,PRODUCT_ID,TIMESTAMPS 
    FROM testingtable2 LATERAL VIEW
        explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts)
        prod_and_ts 
    INNER JOIN table2 A  ON A.BUYER_ID = prod_and_ts.[USER_ID] AND prod_and_ts.timestamps = UNIX_TIMESTAMP (table2.created_time) 
    WHERE prod_and_ts.product_id <> A.ITEM_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BUYER_ID,ITEM_ID,CREATED_TIME,PRODUCT_ID,TIMESTAMPS 
    FROM testingtable2 LATERAL VIEW
            explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts)
            prod_and_ts 
    INNER JOIN table2 A  ON A.BUYER_ID = prod_and_ts.[USER_ID] AND prod_and_ts.product_id = A.ITEM_ID
    WHERE  prod_and_ts.timestamps <> UNIX_TIMESTAMP (table2.created_time) 
) X
```

And here is my **tested TSQL version with my table names for reference:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM SO_Table1HIVE A
    INNER JOIN SO_Table2HIVE B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.[USER_ID] AND B.t1time = A.Created_TIME 
    WHERE B.PRODUCTID <> A.ITEM_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM SO_Table1HIVE A
    INNER JOIN SO_Table2HIVE B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.[USER_ID] AND B.PRODUCTID = A.ITEM_ID  
    WHERE B.t1time <> A.Created_TIME  
 ) X
```

***EDIT PART 3 - UPDATE FOR COMMENT QUESTION ADDITIONAL CRITERIA -PART 2**

In TSQL the entire query (no unions) can be run using  a `FULL OUTER JOIN` with an `OR` condition on the join

```
SELECT * 
FROM SO_Table1HIVE A
FULL OUTER JOIN SO_Table2HIVE B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.[USER_ID] AND (B.t1time = A.Created_TIME OR B.PRODUCTID = A.ITEM_ID)
```

If you can't simply do the above, For the SQL logic for the new criteria - to grab those that don't match from both tables and display them as `NULL` in the other table use `RIGHT JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.
`RIGHT JOIN` will grab anything in the first table the matches the second and everything in the second, and `LEFT` does the opposite.   Add the new queries to your `UNION`.

TSQL EXAMPLE - MODIFY FOR HIVE

```
SELECT * 
FROM SO_Table1HIVE A
RIGHT JOIN SO_Table2HIVE B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.[USER_ID] AND (B.t1time = A.Created_TIME    OR B.PRODUCTID = A.ITEM_ID)
WHERE A.BUYER_ID IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM SO_Table1HIVE A
LEFT JOIN SO_Table2HIVE B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.[USER_ID] AND (B.t1time = A.Created_TIME OR    B.PRODUCTID = A.ITEM_ID)
WHERE B.[USER_ID] IS NULL
```

Or, If you wanted to grab them and match them as duplicates add to `UNION`:

TSQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM SO_Table1HIVE A
JOIN SO_Table2HIVE B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.[USER_ID] 
WHERE B.t1time NOT IN(SELECT Created_TIME FROM SO_Table1HIVE)
AND A.Created_TIME  NOT IN(SELECT t1time FROM SO_Table2HIVE) 
AND B.PRODUCTID NOT IN(SELECT ITEM_ID FROM SO_Table1HIVE)
AND A.ITEM_ID NOT IN(SELECT PRODUCTID FROM SO_Table2HIVE)
```

***Again, Good luck!***

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Really Appreciated. But the problem with `HiveQL` is it doesn't support `INNER JOIN` and NOT EQUALITY `<>` so that is the reason whole problem is coming up for me. I will try this then it will show me the error that INNER JOIN are not supported currently. [https://karmasphere.com/hive-queries-on-table-data](https://karmasphere.com/hive-queries-on-table-data).

Comment: Is there any way around without using `INNER JOIN` and `<>`?

Comment: I think INNER JOIN works, I tried simple query I got some result back. But when I wrote the query in the way you suggested, I am getting some error. I have edited my question basis on your answer, can you point me what wrong I am doing, I think some syntax mistakes I guess. I have updated my question, can you take a look what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Ok. One more update, `INNER JOIN` in Hive is written by simply `JOIN`. I updated my question with the answer. And after running my query, I am not getting  any result back zero result back. And also I have updated my question with actual table name that I am using.

Comment: I just checked in and it looks like you took this, modified the hive syntax,  and got it to work since this comment?  Is that true? (If so, that's great!)

Comment: I have one doubt, where I think your query is failing. Suppose in `SO_Table1HIVE` you have `buyer_id` and corresponding to that you have `item_id` and `created_time`. And you have `SO_Table2HIVE` in which also same `user_id(buyer_id)` is there and corresponding to that `user_id(buyer_id)`, both of them are different(`item_id` and `created_time`) if we compare the two tables on `buyer_id` and `user_id` as I need to make comparisons only on `buyer_id` and `user_id` and after that I need to either `product_id` is not matching with `item_id` or `created_time` is not matching with `timestamps`.

Comment: That is beyond the scope of your OP. SO anything in either table that only matches `USER_ID` to `BUYER_ID` and does not have any other correlation?  Does that happen?  And if so - will it always have a mismatch in the other table?  Even if there are 1 to 1s in the tables, you still have no way left to match it to the first table if there are more than one bad entries.  I will add to my post with updated query with possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use [Hive transform functionality](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-transform.html) and have a custom reducer that does the matching between the records from the two tables: t1 and t2 where t1 is simply TestingTable1 and t2 is

```
   SELECT
      user_id,
      prod_and_ts.product_id as product_id,
      prod_and_ts.timestamps as timestamps
   FROM 
      TestingTable2 
      LATERAL VIEW explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts
```

[as explained by me in another question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373543/explode-the-array-of-struct-in-hive#comment15007330_11373543).

```
FROM (
   FROM (
      SELECT
         buyer_id,
         item_id,
         created_time,
         id 
      FROM (
         SELECT
            buyer_id,
            item_id,
            created_time,
            't1' as id
         FROM
            TestingTable1 t1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
            user_id as buyer_id,
            prod_and_ts.product_id as item_id,
            prod_and_ts.timestamps as created_time,
            't2' as id
         FROM 
            TestingTable2
            LATERAL VIEW explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts
         )t
      )x
      MAP
         buyer_id,
         item_id,
         created_time,
         id
      USING '/bin/cat'
      AS
         buyer_id,
         item_id,
         create_time,
         id
      CLUSTER BY
         buyer_id
      ) map_output
   REDUCE 
      buyer_id,
      item_id,
      create_time,
      id
   USING 'my_custom_reducer'
   AS
      buyer_id,
      item_id,
      create_time,
      product_id,
      timestamps;
```

The above query has 2 distinct portions. The first part is "MAP" and the other is "REDUCE". In between these 2 parts is a phase called *shuffle* (represented by `CLUSTER BY buyer_id`)  that is automatically taken care of my Hive. The Map part of the query reads from tables and also passes an identifier (called *id* that represents which tables the record is coming from). The Shuffle phase groups all the records per *buyer_id*. The Reduce phase will take in the all records for a given *buyer_id* and emit out only the records that satisfy the matching criteria. You will have to write the reducer yourself based on your matching criteria. You can write it in any language of your choice. It's guaranteed that all records that have the same buyer_id will go to the same reducer script.

There might be an easier way to do but this is the method I can think of right now. Good luck! To gain further appreciation of why I chose this method, [see my recent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387543/performance-tuning-a-hive-query/11405841#11405841).

Comment: Thanks Mark for great answer. But I am getting error if I run the above query as it is. Error is- `FAILED: Parse Error: line 18:18 mismatched input 't2' expecting EOF`. Any suggestion why is it happening like this?

Comment: There was a minor typo. Can you please try again?

Comment: Thanks Mark for great answer. I have one more query related to Hive, I have tried but not able to get the answers I need, as HiveQL syntax is totally different with SQL, so having a lot of problem.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405446/find-10-latest-record-for-each-buye‌​r-id-basis-on-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405446/find-10-latest-record-for-each-buye‌​r-id-basis-on-time). It will be of great help to me. Thanks.

Comment: And one more question I have posted, as it is more kind of theoretical question related to Performance measurement.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404163/custom-mapper-and-reduc‌​er-vs-hiveql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404163/custom-mapper-and-reduc‌​er-vs-hiveql). I apologize if I am bothering you so much as on SO, there are not that much BIG DATA expert here. So that is the reason I am pinging you. Really Appreciated all your help...

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried your query again and now I got this error as- `FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 13:6 Invalid Table Alias or Column Reference prod_and_ts`

Comment: There was any problem with your previous query that you posted? meaning the query you previously posted will not work? Just wanted to know, what was the problem in that..

Comment: Yes,there was. A join essentially does a multiplication of the tables. That was not what you wanted.