# Join two similar tables

Tags: sql, join, group-by

This is Table1 data.

```
BUYER_ID     |    ITEM_ID         |      CREATED_TIME 
-------------+--------------------+------------------------
1015826235       220003038067            2001-11-03 19:40:21
1015826235       300003861266            2001-11-08 18:19:59
1015826235       140002997245            2003-08-22 09:23:17
1015826235       200002448035            2001-11-11 22:21:11
1015826235      *260003553381*          *2005-05-27 07:09:56*
1015826235      *260003553382*          *2002-02-02 19:40:39*
2012926235      *260003553383*          *2002-06-01 06:58:47*
```

If you compare the  `Table1` data with the below `Table2` data, then the last three lines are missing in Table2 data after comparison from Table1 data for particular USER_ID with BUYER_ID.

```
USER_ID     |    PRODUCT_ID    |   TIMESTAMPS
------------+------------------+-------------
1015826235       220003038067      1004841621
1015826235       300003861266      1005268799
1015826235       140002997245      1061569397
1015826235       200002448035      1005542471
```

So I need to show either of the two result like this for the above example after JOINING Table1 with Table2-

```
BUYER_ID   |     ITEM_ID       |    CREATED_TIME         |     USER_ID     |       PRODUCT_ID     |   TIMESTAMPS
-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------
1015826235       260003553381       2005-05-27 07:09:56       1015826235          NULL              NULL
1015826235       260003553382       2002-02-02 19:40:39       1015826235          NULL              NULL 
2012926235       260003553383       2002-06-01 06:58:47       2012926235          NULL              NULL
```

**OR**

```
BUYER_ID   |     ITEM_ID       |    CREATED_TIME         |    PRODUCT_ID  |   TIMESTAMPS
-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------
1015826235       260003553381       2005-05-27 07:09:56         NULL              NULL
1015826235       260003553382       2002-02-02 19:40:39         NULL              NULL 
2012926235       260003553383       2002-06-01 06:58:47         NULL              NULL
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are after is the [LEFT JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) operator;

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ITEM_ID = TABLE2.PRODUCT_ID AND Table1.BUYER_ID = Table2.USER_ID 
WHERE Table2.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL
```

What we are effectively saying is "Bring me back all rows from table 2 that have a matching product AND user id, and all those that don't (the LEFT JOIN bit). Then only show me those things that don't have a match in Table 2 (the IS NULL bit)."

Joins are explained neatly here:

[Jeff Atwood's Visual Guide to SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks dash, yes that worked. I have posted one more question on SO, in which nobody has replied yet. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386368/sql-query-join-with-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386368/sql-query-join-with-table). Can you please take a look into that also. It will be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, which will include rows from the source table even if there is no match in the joined table, selecting NULL for fields that would come from it.

```
SELECT Table1.BUYER_ID
     , Table1.ITEM_ID
     , Table1.CREATED_TIME
     , Table2.USER_ID
     , Table2.PRODUCT_ID
     , Table2.TIMESTAMPS
  FROM Table1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.BUYER_ID = Table2.USER_ID
```

You can filter the above to rows that are missing in Table2 (to get your example) by adding

```
 WHERE BUYER_ID NOT IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM Table2)
```

Or, remove the `NOT` to get records where there is a match (your second example).

(You can also use the `WHERE PRODUCT_ID = NULL` as @dash suggested, but it does not express quite the same intent.)

Comment: I agree, but, for efficiency sake, I'd prefer to avoid a correlated sub query. I like the way the NULL check is more a set operation than a data operation though :-)

Comment: But the only problem with this is, for Table2.USER_ID I am getting NULL always.

Comment: Thanks harpo, yes that worked like a charm but the only one problem that I posted above. Thanks for the solution. I have posted one more question on SO, in which nobody has replied yet. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386368/sql-query-join-with-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386368/sql-query-join-with-table). Can you please take a look into that also. It will be of great help to me.