# Join Two Tables and get the output from both of them

Tags: sql, join, group-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query JOIN with Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386368/sql-query-join-with-table)

If this is the data in TestingTable1

```
BUYER_ID  |   ITEM_ID       |  CREATED_TIME
----------+-----------------+----------------------
1345653      151851771618     2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653      110909316904     2012-07-09 21:29:06
1345653      221065796761     2012-07-09 19:31:48
```

And if this is the below data in TestingTable2

```
USER_ID  |   PRODUCT_ID    |    LAST_TIME
---------+----------------+-----------------------
1345653     150851771618      2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653     110909316904      2012-07-09 22:29:06
1345653     221165796761      2012-07-09 12:31:48
```

I need to compare `TestingTable2` with `TestingTable1` on `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID`. I need to see, if `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID` gets matched then I need to compare `ITEM_ID` with `PRODUCT_ID` and `CREATED_TIME` with `LAST_TIME` and if there is a mismatch in `TestingTable2` after comparing with `TestingTable1` in either one of them or both of them, then I need to show the result.

So if you look at the above example- I have three scenarios basically

1. Firstly- In `TestingTable1`, in the First row `ITEM_ID` is not matching with `PRODUCT_ID` in the First row of `TestingTable2` but `CREATED_TIME` is matching with `LAST_TIME` for the first row in both the tables
2. Secondly- In `TestingTable1`, in the Second row `CREATED_TIME` is not matching with `LAST_TIME` in the second row of `TestingTable2` but `ITEM_ID` is matching with `PRODUCT_ID` for the second row in both the tables
3. Thirdly- In `TestingTable1`, in the Third row `ITEM_ID` is not matching with `PRODUCT_ID` and also `CREATED_TIME` is not matching with `LAST_TIME`, so in the third row BOTH of them does not match with `TestingTable1` third row.

So these are three case that I need to cover while comparing `TestingTable2` with `TestingTable1` always. And `TestingTable1` is the MAIN table through which comparisons need to be made always, so it means data in `TestingTable1` is always accurate.

So I need to show the result like this considering the above example if not matching either one of them or both of them- `TestingTable1` data then next to it same `TestingTable2` data, so that I can see what value was there in `TestingTable1` as compared to `TestingTable2`

```
BUYER_ID   |   ITEM_ID       |    CREATED_TIME           |      USER_ID   |     PRODUCT_ID     |     LAST_TIME   
-----------+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------
1345653        151851771618       2012-07-09 19:57:33           1345653        150851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653        110909316904       2012-07-09 21:29:06           1345653        110909316904         2012-07-09 22:29:06
1345653        221065796761       2012-07-09 19:31:48           1345653        221165796761         2012-07-09 12:31:48
```

So I wrote a query, I thought it will cover all my three scenarios, but Only it covered `First Two` not the `Third One`. And I am confuse whether we can achieve this third scenario or not?

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM TestingTable1 A
    JOIN TestingTable2 B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.USER_ID AND B.LAST_TIME = A.Created_TIME 
    WHERE B.PRODUCTID <> A.ITEM_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM TestingTable1 A
    INNER JOIN TestingTable2 B ON A.BUYER_ID = B.USER_ID AND B.PRODUCTID = A.ITEM_ID  
    WHERE B.t1time <> A.Created_TIME  
 ) X
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update:-**

Just a quick update what I was initially thinking to do. As I was aware of few problems with my third scenario.

First of all in `TestingTable1`, I am sorting(ORDER BY) the table by `BUYER_ID` and `CREATED_TIME` and same with `TestingTable2` I am sorting with `USER_ID` and `LAST_TIME` and I am doing comparison by making sure data belongs to `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID` on a given day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with C as
(
  select *
  from TestingTable1 A
    inner join TestingTable2 B
      on A.BUYER_ID = B.USER_ID and
         B.LAST_TIME = A.Created_TIME and
         B.PRODUCT_ID <> A.ITEM_ID
  union all
  select * 
  from TestingTable1 A
    inner join TestingTable2 B 
      on A.BUYER_ID = B.USER_ID and 
         B.PRODUCT_ID = A.ITEM_ID and
         B.LAST_TIME <> A.CREATED_TIME
)
select *
from C
union all
select *
from TestingTable1 A
  inner join TestingTable2 B
    on A.BUYER_ID = B.USER_ID and
       A.CREATED_TIME <> B.LAST_TIME and
       A.ITEM_ID <> B.PRODUCT_ID
where not exists (select *
                  from C
                  where A.BUYER_ID = C.BUYER_ID and
                        A.ITEM_ID = C.ITEM_ID and
                        A.CREATED_TIME = C.CREATED_TIME) and
      not exists (select *
                  from C
                  where B.USER_ID = C.USER_ID and
                        B.PRODUCT_ID = C.PRODUCT_ID and
                        B.LAST_TIME = C.LAST_TIME);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3b6b/5/0)

Comment: Thanks Mikael for the detailed solution. I have posted another similar question in which I need to achieve my third scenario using the query I wrote as my query is working for all the two scenarios, I just need to modify it for the third scenario. And that third scenario question, I haven;t asked before. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464273/multi-join-in-a-single-sql-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464273/multi-join-in-a-single-sql-query). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `non exists` clause to find rows in one table that are not matched in the other.  With `union` you could repeat this for the other table:

```
select  'missing in t2', *
from    TestingTable1 t1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    TestingTable2 t2
        where   t1.buyer_id = t2.user_id
                and t1.item_id = t2.product_id
                and t1.created_time = t2.last_time
        )
union all
select  'missing in t1', *
from    TestingTable2 t2
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    TestingTable1 t1
        where   t1.buyer_id = t2.user_id
                and t1.item_id = t2.product_id
                and t1.created_time = t2.last_time
        )
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14a89/5)

Comment: That doesn't do anything to correlate the two tables though, which is what I think the OP wants.

Comment: That SQL Fiddle is having some problem when I tried to open it.

Comment: @rjchar - what sort of trouble are you having? And what browser are you using? (I'm the owner of SQL Fiddle BTW)

Comment: Thanks lc.for the detailed solution. I have posted another similar question in which I need to achieve my third scenario and that third scenario is totally different from my above question and I need to achieve third scenario using the query I wrote as my query is working for all the two scenarios, I just need to modify it for the third scenario. And that third scenario question, I haven't asked before. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464273/multi-join-in-a-single-sql-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464273/multi-join-in-a-single-sql-query). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is matching all rows in `TestingTable1` without a match in `TestingTable2` with *every possible not-matched row* in `TestingTable2`.

Like this (untested, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
SELECT *
FROM TestingTable1 AS T1
INNER JOIN TestingTable2 AS T2 ON T1.BUYER_ID = T2.USER_ID
    AND
    (
        (
            (T1.ITEM_ID = T2.PRODUCT_ID AND T1.CREATED_TIME <> T2.LAST_TIME)
            OR (T1.ITEM_ID <> T2.PRODUCT_ID AND T1.CREATED_TIME = T2.LAST_TIME)
            OR 
            (
                T1.ITEM_ID <> T2.PRODUCT_ID AND T1.CREATED_TIME <> T2.LAST_TIME
                AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                       FROM TestingTable2 AS T2a
                       INNER JOIN TestingTable1 AS T1a ON T2a.USER_ID = T1a.BUYER_ID
                       AND 
                       (
                           (T1a.ITEM_ID = T2a.PRODUCT_ID AND T1a.CREATED_TIME <> T2a.LAST_TIME)
                           OR (T1a.ITEM_ID <> T2a.PRODUCT_ID AND T1a.CREATED_TIME = T2a.LAST_TIME)
                       )
                       WHERE T1a.BUYER_ID = T1.BUYER_ID
                       AND (T2a.PRODUCT_ID <> T2.PRODUCT_ID OR T2a.LAST_TIME <> T2.LAST_TIME)                       
                      )
            )
        )
    )
```

That is, if you had an additional row in `TestingTable2`:

```
USER_ID  |   PRODUCT_ID   |    LAST_TIME
---------+----------------+-----------------------
1345653     333333333333      2012-07-09 05:27:18
```

your result set would look like:

```
BUYER_ID   |   ITEM_ID       |    CREATED_TIME           |      USER_ID   |     PRODUCT_ID     |     LAST_TIME   
-----------+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------
1345653        151851771618       2012-07-09 19:57:33           1345653        150851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653        110909316904       2012-07-09 21:29:06           1345653        110909316904         2012-07-09 22:29:06
1345653        221065796761       2012-07-09 19:31:48           1345653        221165796761         2012-07-09 12:31:48
1345653        221065796761       2012-07-09 19:31:48           1345653        333333333333         2012-07-09 05:27:18
```

Note that this is **all assuming you have one and only one related row in `TestingTable2`** for each mistaken PRODUCT_ID or LAST_TIME. Otherwise you will get all sorts of crazy Cartesian-product matches! In order to avoid this, you need to determine an ordering for one or both of the tables to determine which row should get matched first.

For example, try adding the following row, which satisfies both scenario 1 and 2, to `TestingTable2` and see what happens:

```
USER_ID  |   PRODUCT_ID   |    LAST_TIME
---------+----------------+-----------------------
1345653     110909316904      2012-07-09 19:57:33
```

Comment: I have updated the question with few pointers that I was initially thinking to use.

Comment: Thanks lc.for the detailed solution. I have posted another similar question in which I need to achieve my third scenario and that third scenario is totally different from my above question and I need to achieve third scenario using the query I wrote as my query is working for all the two scenarios, I just need to modify it for the third scenario. And that third scenario question, I haven;t asked before. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464273/multi-join-in-a-single-sql-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464273/multi-join-in-a-single-sql-query). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is one major problem with the entire attempt.

Because the UserID/BuyerID are identical in every row, the query compares **every row** from TestingTable1 with **every row** from TestingTable2.

It is only by coincidence that the first two comparisons worked for you;
If you had several rows with similar CREATED_TIME (even with different ITEM_IDs) they would be compared to each other.

What I recommend is this:
Add a `primary key` for each table, and a `foreign key` that will connect them.
That way, you will be able to compare each row in TestingTable1 to its equivalent in TestingTable2, without result in a "Cartesian product".

Comment: I have updated my question with few pointers what I was initially thinking to do.

Comment: @rjchar Are you saying that the third scenario only checks for differences on the same day?

Comment: All the three scenarios will be checked on for a given day. Firstly I will sort the `Table1` on `BUYER_ID` and `CREATED_TIME` for a given day and there will be only 5 entries for each `BUYER_ID` in `Table1`. Similarly I will sort the `Table2` on `USER_ID` and `LAST_TIME` for a given day and there will be only 5 entries for each `USER_ID` in `Table2`. And then I will be doing comparisons on both of the table, as everything will get sorted basis on time and then I can do the comparisons.