# Find TOP 10 latest record for each BUYER_ID for yesterday's date

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, hive, hiveql

This is the below table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestingTable1 
( 
BUYER_ID BIGINT,
ITEM_ID BIGINT, 
CREATED_TIME STRING
)
```

And this is the below data in the above table-

```
BUYER_ID    |    ITEM_ID       |    CREATED_TIME
------------+------------------+-----------------------
1015826235      220003038067        2012-07-09 19:40:21,
1015826235      300003861266        2012-07-09 18:19:59,
1015826235      140002997245        2012-07-09 09:23:17,
1015826235      210002448035        2012-07-09 22:21:11,
1015826235      260003553381        2012-07-09 07:09:56,
1015826235      260003553382        2012-07-09 19:40:39,
1015826235      260003553383        2012-07-09 06:58:47,
1015826235      260003553384        2012-07-09 07:28:47,
1015826235      260003553385        2012-07-09 08:48:47,
1015826235      260003553386        2012-07-09 06:38:47,
1015826235      260003553387        2012-07-09 05:38:47,
1015826235      260003553388        2012-07-09 04:55:47,
1015826235      260003553389        2012-07-09 06:54:37,
34512201        597245693           2012-07-09 16:20:21,
34512201        8071787728          2012-07-09 15:19:59,
34512201        5868222883          2012-07-09 08:23:17,
34512201        2412180494          2012-07-09 22:21:11,
34512201        2422054205          2012-07-09 06:09:56,
34512201        1875744030          2012-07-09 19:40:39,
34512201        5639158173          2012-07-09 06:58:47,
34512201        5656232360          2012-07-09 07:28:47, 
34512201        959188449           2012-07-09 08:48:47,
34512201        4645350592          2012-07-09 06:38:47,
34512201        5657320532          2012-07-09 05:38:47,
34512201        290419656539        2012-07-09 04:55:47,
```

If you see the above data in the table, there are only two UNIQUE `BUYER_ID` and corresponding to those I have `ITEM_ID` AND `CREATED_TIME`. I need only 10 latest record basis on the time for the day before today's date whenever I will be firing this query (meaning yesterday's date) for each `BUYER_ID`.

So for this `BUYER_ID` - `34512201` I need 10 latest record for each `BUYER_ID` basis on `CREATED_TIME` for yesterday's date only.

And each `BUYER_ID` can have any day's data. But I am specifically interested for day before  today's data(means yesterday's date always) by checking at the `CREATED_TIME`

**Find `TOP 10` latest data for each `BUYER_ID` for yesterday's date. Below is the sample output I should be getting corresponding to each `BUYER_ID`.**

Sample Output.

```
BUYER_ID    |    ITEM_ID       |    CREATED_TIME
------------+------------------+-----------------------
34512201        2412180494          2012-07-09 22:21:11
34512201        1875744030          2012-07-09 19:40:39
34512201        597245693           2012-07-09 16:20:21
34512201        8071787728          2012-07-09 15:19:59
34512201        959188449           2012-07-09 08:48:47
34512201        5868222883          2012-07-09 08:23:17
34512201        5656232360          2012-07-09 07:28:47 
34512201        5639158173          2012-07-09 06:58:47
34512201        4645350592          2012-07-09 06:38:47
34512201        2422054205          2012-07-09 06:09:56
1015826235      210002448035        2012-07-09 22:21:11
1015826235      260003553382        2012-07-09 19:40:39
1015826235      220003038067        2012-07-09 19:40:21
1015826235      300003861266        2012-07-09 18:19:59
1015826235      140002997245        2012-07-09 09:23:17
1015826235      260003553385        2012-07-09 08:48:47
1015826235      260003553384        2012-07-09 07:28:47
1015826235      260003553381        2012-07-09 07:09:56
1015826235      260003553383        2012-07-09 06:58:47
1015826235      260003553389        2012-07-09 06:54:37
```

I am working with `Hive` and `Hive` supports SQL like syntax. So I need to make sure the SQL should work in Hive environment too.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Update:-**

I am using the below query and I need to get top 10 latest from the below query and need to add one more qualifier for date check, means in `where clause for yesterday's date`- I cannot use `TOP 10` here as Hive doesn't support `TOP 10` sql syntax. I need some other way to do this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM TestingTable1 WHERE ORDER BY buyer_id, created_time DESC;
```

**One More UPDATE:-**

I wrote this below query with the use of `RANK UserDefinedFunction`.

```
SELECT buyer_id, item_id, created_time, rk
FROM (
    SELECT buyer_id, item_id, rank(item_id) as rk, created_time
    FROM testingtable1
    DISTRIBUTE BY buyer_id, item_id
    SORT BY buyer_id, item_id, created_time desc
) a 
WHERE rk < 10
ORDER BY buyer_id, created_time, rk;
```

And this is the RANK UDF functions in Java-

```
package com.example.hive.udf;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

    public final class Rank extends UDF{
        private int  counter;
        private String last_key;
        public int evaluate(final String key){
          if ( !key.equalsIgnoreCase(this.last_key) ) {
             this.counter = 0;
             this.last_key = key;
          }
          return this.counter++;
        }
    }
```

And above query is not work the way I wanted to, some sort of twist has to be made I guess in that query.

**Is there any way to do this without using any UDF in HiveQL?**

Comment: You should say specifically which SQL Language you're using.

Comment: I am working with Hive and Hive supports SQL Like syntax, so that is the reason I tag this question as `SQL`. I think oracle syntax will work fine here.

Comment: @Bohemian, Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: I don't know how the Rank function works in this DBMS, but the `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause looks like `PARTITION BY` in SQL Server, so I would guess you need to remove the `item_id` column from that clause.

Comment: RANK is not a function, it's a UDF that I have created, you can see my edit that I just did in my question. By looking at the question, you will understand what I am talking about. Can you provide me the exact query that you just said to me. As that way I will understand more.

Comment: Note that this answer has a **BUG**, you must use another subquery in which you use DISTRIBUTE/SORT BY and use rank() from outer query. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15805396/191069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT FIRST 10 *
    FROM TestingTable1
   WHERE buyer_id = 34512201
ORDER BY created_time DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks Frank for commenting out. I am not specific to that `buyer_id`. It can be many. And I don't need First 10. I need latest for that particular day. By latest means last 10 time for that particular `BUYER_ID` in desc order

Comment: Since you gave that example, I used it for my example :) .. well, by ORDERing created_time in DESCending, the FIRST 10 would be the latest 10 rows? ..ahh, why is created_time not defined as a DATETIME datatype?.. and if you want a previous days results, you can add a qualifier to the WHERE clause.

Comment: I have no idea why they didn't defined as `DATETIME` datatype. I am working on someone else design. They have defined that as a string. So I have to use that I guess. I have also posted sample output.

Comment: then you can cast that string to a DATETIME. The STRING is in proper DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND format!

Comment: And how can I enable this to all the `BUYER_ID` as currently it has enabled for only one. Can you provide me the example which can work in my scenario. it will be of great help to me. And `FIRST 10.*` will not work with Hive, as I am working in Hive and Hive supports SQL like syntax.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hive, this example works for Informix, however not much different for other DB's.. remove buyer_id qualifier from the WHERE clause and ORDER BY buyer_id, created_time DESC.

Comment: I tried using that and I am working with Hive and `FIRST 10.*` doesn't working in that. Is there any other way apart from that?

Comment: not sure.. there must be some equivalent for obtaining the FIRST/LAST 10 rows of the result set in hive?.. perhaps some other ORM, like Hibernate, provides examples of how to obtain FIRST 10 rows?

Comment: I just did the searching, but couldn't found out anything.

Comment: I think using TOP 10 will do the trick! http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/extract-top-n-records-in-each-group-in-hadoophive/

Comment: I tried using this `SELECT TOP 10 FROM TestingTable1 WHERE ORDER BY buyer_id, created_time DESC;` and it doesn't works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13642/discussion-between-frank-computer-and-rjchar)

Comment: Could HQL LIMIT 10 or using COUNT work?.. see https://karmasphere.com/20101004185/Karmasphere-Analyst/hive-queries-on-table-data#syntax_of_sort_by

Comment: LIMIT will restrict the whole query to 10 but I need TOP 10 for each BUYER_ID. That's is causing more problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13644/discussion-between-frank-computer-and-rjchar)

Comment: @Frank I think you're missing something here.. The asker wants the top 10 for EACH GROUP. Not just a single group.

Answer (score 0):

I am late answering this and I am sure you must be knowing the use of row_number function with Hive. Just an addition as a reference to previously good discussion.

```
select * from
(select buyer_id,item_id,created_time, row_number() over(partition by buyer_id over
created_time asc) row_num from yourtable)tab
where tab.row_num<=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (select buyer_id,item_id,created_time,row_num() over (partition by buyer_id order by created_time DESC)) a 
where a.row_num<=10
```

Comment: Please add some commentary to your answer. *Why* will this work, and how is it different than the other answers. Also, maybe you didn't realize, but this question is 7 years old.